# Fetch the list of shared drives using PHP on Windows?

Tags: php, windows

I want to display the list of shared drives connected to my system running Windows. Is there any tutorial for this?

I have tried the following code in PHP:

```
echo "<select id = 'drives'><option>Drives</option>";
for ($ii=66;$ii<92;$ii++) 
{
    $char = chr($ii);
    if (opendir($char.":/"))
        echo "<option>".$char."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Are you expecting to find the drives connected on the web server?  Do you want to find the mapped drives on someone's computer connected with a web browser?  Are you doing php-gtk?  What is the context.

Comment: can you please review the answers you have been given and either accept the one that helped you most/solved your problem or point out why none of the answers solved your problem. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the experimental Win32 API functions in PHP:

1. Register the API function `GetDriveType` using [w32api-register-function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.w32api-register-function.php).
2. After that you can call this function either by using [w32api-invoke-function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.w32api-invoke-function.php) or by directly calling `GetDriveType`. It depends on your PHP version. (See the user contributed note at the bottom of the documentation of [w32api-invoke-function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.w32api-invoke-function.php)!)
3. Check the return value if it is `DRIVE_REMOTE`. You can find the required parameters and the list of other return values at the MSDN documentation of [GetDriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate Windows shared resources via [PHP's COM API](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php):

```
$wmi = new COM('WinMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!root/cimv2');
$result = $wmi->ExecQuery('Select Path from Win32_Share where Type = 0');
foreach ($result as $share) {
    echo $share->Path, PHP_EOL;
}
```

The output will list all shared folders on the machine. Type `0` is a disk drive.

See the MSDN documentation for [`Win32_Share`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for additional properties you can query.

**Note:** if you are looking for *Mapped Network Drives*, change the query to

```
Select ProviderName From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 4
```

and change `$share->Path` to `$share->ProviderName`

See this [Technet Article](https://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/10/27/how-can-i-determine-which-drives-are-mapped-to-network-shares.aspx) for details.

---

An alternative to using COM would be to use the `wmic` command:

```
exec('wmic Share where Type=0 get Path', $shares);
print_r($shares);
```

is equivalent to the first example above. For more details on `WMIC`, see

- [WMIC - Take Command-line Control over WMI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) and
- [Windows Management Instrumentation Command](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)

Answer (score 0):

This may help to do it under c#. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/networkshares.aspx
I can't find any way to do it directly under php.

To use this with your php you may need make this as a dll and call it from php using the Win32 api functions.

Comment: it's ok , in php is there any function to open a remote directory directly ?(i specify the drive letter before the program runs)