# Fetch the drive contents dynamically

Tags: php

in my project i have a situation that when i select the drive letter it display the corresponding files with in the share drive will dispaly . for that i find the connected drives with my system using the following code

```
echo "<select id = 'drives'><option>Drives</option>";
for ($ii=66;$ii<92;$ii++) {
    $char = chr($ii);
    if(opendir($char.":/")) echo "<option>".$char."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";`
```

But i select the drive letters the corresponding files are not displayed. Please help me to fetch the files. Thanks in advance

Comment: do we have to ask this twice?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642266/fetch-the-list-of-share-drives-connected-with-my-system

Answer (score 1):

A neat way to do it is with a [`DirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/DirectoryIterator):

```
$it = new DirectoryIterator($char . ':/');
foreach ($it as $file)
    echo $file->getFilename();
```

See also [`SPLFileInfo`](http://www.php.net/SplFileInfo).